# What is the best way to sanitize your hands when working with mushrooms?

Tags: mushrooms

I've been bleaching my hands before working with mushrooms, and am getting white spots on my cloths. What is the best way to sanitize your hands before I reach my hands into the moisture chamber to work with the kit?

Comment: How about using gloves? The disposable ones would need no special treatment and the thick ones can be sanitized without destroying your skin.

Comment: sanitizing my hands in some way safe to the mushrooms is better in my opinion

Comment: If you are using full strength bleach, that's likely your problem. For most purposes a 10:1 water:bleach ratio is more than enough for disinfection.

Answer (score 2):

I think ***best*** might be subjective here.

Personally when working with mushrooms / mycellium I wash my arms & hands with soap and water & then put on disposable gloves. I then spray the gloves with a 50/50 water isopropyl alcohol mixture & let the gloves dry before proceeding with my work.

You can use this mixture on your skin too, although it will start to dry out your skin after a while. I do sometimes do this.

A mix of 50% to 70% isopropyl alcohol is a much better choice than bleach. It is less toxic & won't stain your clothes.